# Separating Javis.jl `Video` and `Object` two different blocks in Pluto

Tags: julia, pluto.jl

I am trying to learn [Javis.jl](https://juliaanimators.github.io/Javis.jl/stable/) with Pluto notebooks. While doing the [tutorial](https://juliaanimators.github.io/Javis.jl/stable/tutorials/tutorial_1/), I tried separating the `Video` object and the `Object` in different Pluto blocks, as shown:

```
md"""
Some md here
"""
begin
    myvideo = Video(500, 500)
    Background(1:70, ground)
end

md"""
Some markdown here. Separate block.
"""

begin
    red_ball = Object(....)
    blue_ball = Object(....)
end
```

which shows me an error saying

```
A `Video` must be defined before an `Object`

var"#Object#10"(::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}}, ::Type{Javis.Object}, ::Symbol, ::Function, ::Luxor.Point)@Object.jl:77
...
```

This error does not occur if I put the `myvideo` and the `Background` in the same `begin...end` block as the `red_ball` and `blue_ball`.

Upon source code inspection, calling `Video()` sets a global variable in the environment so it is not clear to me how this happened.

Any ideas on what could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: It's actually not helpful to split it into different parts atm. As only the `myvideo` is referenced in the `render` function but not the objects. This results in the fact that changing the objects will not trigger a rerendering in pluto. When they are in the same `begin ... end` it will work as the whole blog is executed which results in a change of the `myvideo` and then triggers rendering even if `render` is in a different block.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure but I think it might be because `Pluto` creates a different `Module` for each cell, so perhaps the Object can't see the right `CURRENT_VIDEO` constant from the other cell.

If I can ask you, why do you want to use different cells?

Comment: Thanks. Checking the source code of my jl file, it seems that it does not do this per cell. Maybe there's something else happening in Pluto's backend.

As for the reason, I merely wanted to organize my code by separating Objects, animations, and the video, each with different Markdown explanations. But it seems that it wouldn't work for now. But thanks!